# If $z\in C$, why is $z^6 = (1+i)^2$ not equivalent to $z^3 = 1+i$ but $(z+\frac{3}{4}i)^3 = i$ is indeed equivalent to $z+\frac{3}{4}i = \sqrt[3]i$

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, complex-analysis

I can't see why there would be a difference in the approach to these two problems.

Comment: I'm not certain of any other implications, but $z^6 = (1 + i)^2$ is actually equivalent to $z^3 = \pm(1 + i)$.

Answer (score 0):

When you square you lose the chance to see any factor $-1$, so you are effective adding solutions: if $z^3=1+i$, then $(-z)^3=-1-i$, but $z^6=(-z)^6$.

In the second case, you are just playing (badly) with the notation $\sqrt[3]i$, which hides the fact that you are looking at the equation $z+3i/4=w$ where $w$ is a cubic root of $i$.

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

- How many (complex) roots does $z^6=(1+i)^2$ have vs. $z^3=1+i$?
- How many values does the (multi-valued) $\sqrt[3]{i}$ have?